# Is there a way to create CI/CD pipeline with Nx on Lerna Monorepo?

Tags: monorepo, nrwl-nx, lerna

I have a monorepo based on Lerna and I'd like to improve the experience by integrating with Nx.
Successfully, added Nx.json and update some configuration by following the tutorial (https://nx.dev/recipes/adopting-nx/lerna-and-nx), but CI/CD pipeline is still not working.
And also I am not going to use nx/cloud, instead I am using nx/tasks-runners/default as a default runner.

Please let me know if you have any good example or experience for it.

I verified these scripts are working.

`package.json/scripts: { "build": "nx run-many --target=build", "test": "nx run-many --target=test" }`

Current CI.yml:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0,
      - name: "Install dependencies"
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run bootstrap
      - name: "Run Build"    
        run: npm run build          
  publish:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2       
      - name: "Update Version"
        run: |   
          npx lerna version
      - name: "Publish"    
        run: |
          npx lerna publish
```

Hope to update this one with Nx.